# pgAdmin Postgresql User Input Conditional

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, datetime, check-constraints

I work with pgadmin4-postgresql and I created a table with name, age, and email columns. I want to add condition for age column but I cannot. For example age interval is between 18 < age < 90 and when I try to add a new person with age 95, raise an error..

```
input =int('Age:')
if 18 < input < 90:
    print("Age value must be between interval")
```

How can I implement this python code on the postgresql, please help me? Thank you...

Comment: You shouldn't store age in your table, because people tend to become older every year, and the age values will soon be out-of-date. Store DOB instead.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when an 89 year old person in your table turns 90?

Comment: @jarlh I agree with your opinion, but what I wanted to learn here was how to implement condition in postgresql and I wanted to explain this with age in the example.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you are describing the concept of a SQL check constraint. This is bound with the definition of your table:

```
create table mytable (
    id serial primary key,
    name text,
    email text,
    age int,
    check(age > 18 and age < 90)
)
```

The constraint ensures that values stored to column `age` belong to the given range; if an attempt is made to insert an offending value, then an error is raised, and the value is rejected.

Note that storing the age is usually not a good practice; an age literally changes all the time. Storing the date of birth is much better.

Comment: Thank you so much @GMB.